# How to Access a Record Value Dynamically by its API Field Name, in the Aura Component Markup (Without JavaScript)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to list records with dynamically selected fields, so a have a record list and a field list:

[image: 1]

In JavaScript I would just loop through the records and then the fields, and access the value by its key:

[image: 2]

But trying that in the Aura markup does not even compile:

[image: 3]

Similar errors happen if i try to use `{! record[ProductCode] }` or `{! record['ProductCode'] }`.

I could use JavaScript to manipulate these lists (and I probably will, if there is no other way), but is it possible to make this work using these same lists? am i missing something, using wrong syntax or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it in this way.
The data structure should be flat. Try something like that.

```js
const records = recordList.map(record => {
    return fieldList.map(field => ({
       field: field,
       value: record[field]
    }));
})
```

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <aura:iteration items="{!record}" var="recordObject">
       {!recordObject.field} - {!recordObject.value}
   </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Hi Piotr Gajek! it's a shame that the markup doesn't support this.. Thank you for the example, it's helping a lot.